# Using web fonts

Tags: webfonts

I use some fonts in my new website that do not exist by default on normal user computers.
After some search I got that there are some tools that might help, like [Google web-fonts](http://www.google.com/webfonts). 
Fonts that I used are : [Bebas](http://www.dafont.com/bebas.font) , [Sansation](http://www.dafont.com/sansation.font) and [Quicksand](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/Quicksand)
But I couldn't find them on Google web fonts.
How do I do use these fonts ?

 And what are other cross browser solutions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Different fonts are created by different font foundries. Not all fonts will be found in the same place. And not all fonts are available to be used as web fonts because of font-licensing.

Fonts are not always free and good fonts are rarely free.

You can usually find out if a font is available as a web font, and who owns the font by googling the font name plus "@font-face".

You absolutely should know where you'll be getting the fonts you'll be working with in advance. If you have three fonts that come from three different font-services then that's bad. Firefox especially wont like it much and you'll have some pretty bad [fout](http://paulirish.com/2009/fighting-the-font-face-fout/) problems.

Fortunately for you, all those fonts are available through font-squirrel

**Bebas**
http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontfacedemo/Bebas

**Sansation**
http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/Sansation

**Quicksand**
http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/Quicksand

What you will want to do is download all those fonts, them run them through the @font-face generator

https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator

**HOWEVER** It reads to me like you don't really understand what @font-face is, or how it works. So I'd recommend reading up on it some more.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what exactly you mean, but if you want to convert your website's font into a custom font which is viewable for the visitor, you could try use the [curfon](http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/) solution.